# Force code to execute in order?

Tags: c#, order-of-execution

I am seeing a strange problem in my C# code. I have something like this:

```
public static class ErrorHandler {
  public static int ErrorIgnoreCount = 0;
  public static void IncrementIgnoreCount() {
    ErrorIgnoreCount++;
  }
  public static void DecrementIgnoreCount() {
    ErrorIgnoreCount--;
  }
  public static void DoHandleError() {
    // actual error handling code here
  }
  public static void HandleError() { 
    if (ErrorIgnoreCount == 0) {
      DoHandleError();
    }
  }
}

public class SomeClass {

  public void DoSomething() {
    ErrorHandler.IncrementIgnoreCount();
    CodeThatIsSupposedToGenerateErrors(); // some method; not shown
    ErrorHandler.DecrementIgnoreCount();
  }
}
```

The problem is that the compiler often decides that the order of the three calls in the DoSomething() method is not important. For example, the decrement may happen before the increment. The result is that when the code that is supposed to generate errors is run, the error handling code fires, which I don't want.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Is that in a multithreaded setting? Otherwise i can't see how this would not follow the execution order.

Comment: Consider using the [`lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) keyword.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? This code demonstrates nothing.

Comment: the code in DoSomething will execute in the right order. But if during the executtion of CodeThatIsSupposedToGenerateErrors another thread runs DoSomething, that threat will mess up the value of the ErrorIgnoreCount

Comment: The problem is that the CodeThatIsSupposedToGenerateErrors is typically calling an ANTLR parser. Yes, on the same thread. But I'll try.

Comment: `if (ErrorIgnoreCount = 0)` is probably supposed to be `==`, right?

Comment: Yes, and in the actual project it is. Fixed.

Comment: So what makes you think that compiler is somehow involved here?

Comment: That's an assumption on my part I guess . . . At one point I was having the increment check for a negative value, and that would fire from time to time, even when I was doing all the increment/decrement calls via a using to make sure I didn't mess up the order or forget one of them . . .

Comment: If you call that from multiple threads then it's perfectly possible. If everything is within single thread - doubt that.

Comment: The sequence of three calls -- increment, DoSomething, decrement is sometimes called from different threads, yes. But each sequence is itself within a single thread. I am OK with it if the error code sometimes fails to fire, because another thread has bumped the ignore count. I may now see it -- the ++ and -- themselves may not be thread safe in C#. I was coming from another language where they were. That faulty assumption may be my problem.  I may try locking within the increment/decrement calls, as one commenter suggested. I just noticed Interlocked.Increment, which may be better.

Comment: The compiler will not change the order of execution of the methods called in DoSomething()  Something else is interfering. Use the debugger and step through it.

Comment: RE: _The sequence of three calls -- increment, DoSomething, decrement is sometimes called from different threads_ As some have said before, you can not guarantee the **atomicity** in the absence of a `lock`. It's perfectly possible that thread T1 calls `IncrementIgnoreCount`, T2 does that too and then T1 again calls `CodeThatIsSupposedToGenerateErrors` by which time the count would have been modified (by T2). From the point of view of each thread, sequence is guaranteed, but they can interfere. Thanks though for pointing out that ++/-- are not thread safe in C#. Never realised that.

Answer (score 0):

Add Trace or Logs to your code in `IncrementIgnoreCount`, `DecrementIgnoreCount` and `HandleError` function.

That will help you to view real call order.